# Error: 'No Persistence provider for EntityManager' under Hibernate 5.3.0.Beta1

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

In Eclipse, I set up a new maven project where I want to try some database connection. So I created a User.java which is my entity and a `DataBaseConnector.java` where I try the db connection but I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named mysql-database
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at database.DataBaseConnector.getTestConnection(DataBaseConnector.java:21)
at database.DataBaseConnector.main(DataBaseConnector.java:14)
```

My current version of the persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="mysql-database" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <description>DataBase Connection</description>

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sharifo" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234" />

            <!-- <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"  /-->
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"  /-->
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" /-->
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>backend</groupId>
  <artifactId>shareifo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>


     <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.8-dmr</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

I have the feeling that the persistence.xml might be mis-configured, so i uploaded my project also on github:
https://github.com/ViFire/sherifo-backend.git.

I dont know how to fix or handle this error. Do you have ny tips for me?

Answer (score 2):

I checked out the code via the GitHub project link you provided. Two things had to be changed:

1. Remove from `pom.xml` the now obsolete dependency:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

   **Note**: This dependency is no longer needed and might even be confusing at runtime, as Hibernate 5.3.xyz now depends on `javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2`, the official JPA 2.2 *spec*-jar.
2. Change the `persistence.xml` so it reads like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
                version="2.1">
       <persistence-unit name="mysql-database" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

           <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
           <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>

           <properties>
               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sharifo" />
               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="admin" />
               <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234" />

               <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>

               <!--
                   <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
                   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
               -->
           </properties>
       </persistence-unit>
   </persistence>
   ```

   **Note well**,

   - (a) the different *xmlns* and JPA version (2.1) in the header,
   - (b) `provider` is: `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`,
   - (c) `jdbc.driver` is: `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.

#### Observations

While debugging/testing, I found that the *5.3.0.Beta1* version of Hibernate seems to behave different than, e.g., the latest stable version: *5.2.17.Final*. The "misleading" error message you observed will be thrown, even if everything is setup as described above.

For me this had a simple reason: In case the DB is not reachable or the credentials are incorrect, you will also encounter the message:

> No Persistence provider for EntityManager named xyz...

which is - IMHO - totally confusing in this context. With Hibernate *5.2.x*.Final you get an error message on the failing connection attempt, including a more precise debugging output for what to look for exactly.

For the aforementioned reason: **Carefully** check whether user/pw, JDBC url/hostname are correct as this might end up in a confusing error message on the non-existence of a Persistence-Provider for a Persistence-Unit that is actually available and configured correctly.

As a bonus, I will open a Pull request (PR) on your GitHub project which you can check in detail. I hope you will integrate this PR back into your project so you benefit directly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @vifire: PR is open, see: https://github.com/ViFire/sherifo-backend/pulls